AWS CDK ALB/NLB S3 Bucket Access Denied
I'm using AWS CDK in TypeScript to deploy a stack with ALB and NLB load balancers. The stack seems to be fine up until the point at which it associates the S3 log buckets when I get an Access Denied error on the ELB access. Here's the code I have:
const elbAccountIds: { [region: string]: string } = {
      'us-east-1': '127311923021',
      'us-east-2': '033677994240',
      'us-west-1': '027434742980',
      'us-west-2': '797873946194',
      // Add other regions as needed
    };

    const currentRegion = cdk.Stack.of(this).region;
    const elbAccountId = elbAccountIds[currentRegion];
    if (!elbAccountId) {
      throw new Error(`ELB Account ID not defined for region ${currentRegion}`);
    }

    // Create S3 bucket for LB logs
    const logBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'LBLogsBucket', {
      bucketName: `${PROJECT_NAME}-lb-logs-bucket-${cdk.Aws.ACCOUNT_ID}`,
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
      enforceSSL: true,
      versioned: true,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    // Deny insecure transport
    logBucket.addToResourcePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        sid: 'DenyInsecureTransport',
        principals: [new iam.AnyPrincipal()],
        effect: iam.Effect.DENY,
        actions: ['s3:*'],
        resources: [logBucket.bucketArn, logBucket.arnForObjects('*')],
        conditions: {
          Bool: { 'aws:SecureTransport': 'false' },
        },
      })
    );

    logBucket.addToResourcePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        sid: 'AWSLogDeliveryPolicy',
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        principals: [
          new iam.ServicePrincipal('*'),
          new iam.AccountPrincipal(elbAccountId),
          new iam.AccountPrincipal(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID),
        ],
        actions: ['s3:*'],
        resources: [logBucket.bucketArn, `${logBucket.bucketArn}/*`],
        conditions: {
          StringEquals: {
            'aws:SourceAccount': AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
          },
          ArnLike: {
            'aws:SourceArn': `arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}:*`,
          },
        },
      })
    );

I'm attaching the attributes with the following:
const cfnAlb = alb.node.defaultChild as elbv2.CfnLoadBalancer;
    cfnAlb.loadBalancerAttributes = [
      { key: 'deletion_protection.enabled', value: 'true' },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.enabled', value: 'true' },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.bucket', value: logBucket.bucketName },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.prefix', value: 'ALBLogs' },
      { key: 'routing.http.drop_invalid_header_fields.enabled', value: 'true' },
    ];

    const cfnNlb = nlb.node.defaultChild as elbv2.CfnLoadBalancer;
    cfnNlb.loadBalancerAttributes = [
      { key: 'deletion_protection.enabled', value: 'true' },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.enabled', value: 'true' },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.bucket', value: logBucket.bucketName },
      { key: 'access_logs.s3.prefix', value: `NLBLogs/${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}` },
    ];

I have the bucket permissions fairly wide open and am attaching the region elb account ID to the principal.

Please add the error message to the question - it usually helps with figuring out the nature of the permission issue.
